# Plot option 'bg' not working

Tags: r, plot

I have a very basic piece of R code here, as well as the plot it produces. Why is the dot not filled in red?

```
plot(1, 1, col="blue", bg="red", cex=4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use one of `pch =` 21 through 25 for `bg` to work

```
plot(1, 1, col = "blue", pch = 21, bg = "red", cex = 4)
```

From the `points` help file:

> **bg**
>
> background (fill) color for the open plot symbols given by `pch = 21:25`.

[image]